# Matplotlib pie charts as scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an interesting problem where I am trying to use multiple matplotlib pie charts as a scatter plot. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib) regarding [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html) matplotlib tutorial and was able to get those working. However, I found that I was able to achieve the same results using the built-in pie function and plotting many pie charts on the same axis.

When using this alternative method, I found that after plotting the pie charts the axes lose their labels and whenever you pan the original data is still contained inside of the where the bounds of the original data should be, but the pie charts are only contained inside of the figure canvas.

The following code replicates the issue that I'm having.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

def rand(): #simulate some random data
    return [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(10)]

def plot_pie(x, ax): 
    ax.pie(x[['a','b','c']], center=(x['lat'],x['lon']), radius=1,colors=['r', 'b', 'g'])

#my data is stored in a similar styled dataframe that I read from a csv and the data is static
sim_data = pd.DataFrame({'a':rand(),'b':rand(),'c':rand(), 'lat':rand(),'lon':rand()})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(x=sim_data['lat'], y=sim_data['lon'], s=1000, facecolor='none',edgecolors='r')
y_init = ax.get_ylim()
x_init = ax.get_xlim()

sim_data.apply(lambda x : plot_pie(x,ax), axis=1)
ax.set_ylim(y_init)
ax.set_xlim(x_init)
plt.show()
```

The reason that I reset the x and y limits of the axis is that I assume the pie function automatically sets the bounds of the axes to the last pie chart and this was my work around.

UPDATE

After reading the docs again I found that matplotlib pie chart objects as a default are set to not clip to the extents of any axes. To solve it, just updating that parameter seemed to work for me. The following code is the solution to my problem. I also found that by plotting each pie chart I would lose my axes ticks, to solve that I had to pass the frame parameter to the pie charts.

```
def plot_pie(x, ax):
    ax.pie(x[['a','b','c']], center=(x['lat'],x['lon']), radius=1,colors=['r', 'b', 'g'], wedgeprops={'clip_on':True}, frame=True)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Have you considered more classical plot variants, why you want to use pie cjarts in a scatter plot?

Comment: Only reason that I'm even trying this is because I was tasked with building a GUI for an agent based model and was asked to try and put a pie chart at pois that represents the status of each agent. I agree that it's probably a bad idea tho.

Comment: `ax.set_ylim(y_int[0]-10, y_init[1]+10);ax.set_xlim(x_init[0]-10, y_init[1]+10)`How about expanding the drawing area of the graph?

Comment: [What your code generates](https://imgur.com/s2r86SU),

[What you are, supposedly trying to achieve](https://imgur.com/NDCVxQu) 

Please, write me back If my guess right or post an image with desired result somewhere.

Comment: The @r-beginners will work if you just want to keep all your big markers on the figure [keep all your big markers on the figure](https://imgur.com/lxs2zes)

Comment: [All three variants on a single plot](https://imgur.com/L8ce7AY)

Comment: I suppose that I may not have accurately described the problem that I'm having. I know that expanding the drawing area of the graph would let me show everything without any issue. My main concern is that when I pan or zoom on the graph, the pie charts are not really limited by the constraints of the axes. I think that setting the x and y limits only affects any point that I draw on the axes and not the pie charts. @banderlog13 Could you show me the code that you used in your example?

Comment: Update: I figured it out, it has to do with setting the patches objects property of clip_on to True. For some reason the default is set to False. Thank you all for your help, I'm going to update my question to include the solution to this problem.

Comment: @jlardy I've posted code for examples below. Also, I've run your updated code, but I am still unsure how the result is different, except now we can see axes with ticks: https://i.imgur.com/88ywmrO.png

Comment: If you run the original code, try and pan around or zoom in using the built-in pan feature. When you do that, you should see the behavior that I was trying to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Data generated as in original post. I added a frame for each plot for clarity.

```py
def plot_pie(x, ax, r=1): 
    # radius for pieplot size on a scatterplot
    ax.pie(x[['a','b','c']], center=(x['lat'],x['lon']), radius=r, colors=['r', 'b', 'g'])

    
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

# original plot
ax = axs[0]
ax.scatter(x=sim_data['lat'], y=sim_data['lon'], s=1000, facecolor='none', edgecolors='r')
y_init = ax.get_ylim()
x_init = ax.get_xlim()
sim_data.apply(lambda x : plot_pie(x,ax), axis=1)
ax.set_ylim(y_init)
ax.set_xlim(x_init)
ax.set_title('Original')
ax.set_frame_on(True)

# r-beginner's solution
ax = axs[1]
ax.scatter(x=sim_data['lat'], y=sim_data['lon'], s=1000, facecolor='none', edgecolors='r')
y_init = ax.get_ylim()
x_init = ax.get_xlim()
sim_data.apply(lambda x : plot_pie(x,ax), axis=1)
ax.set_ylim([0, y_init[1]*1.1])
ax.set_xlim([0, x_init[1]*1.1])
ax.set_title('r-beginners')
ax.set_frame_on(True)

# my solution
ax = axs[2]
# do not use `s=` for size, it will not work properly when you are scattering pieplots
# because pieplots will be plotted above them
ax.scatter(x=sim_data['lat'], y=sim_data['lon'], s=0)
# git min/max values for the axes
y_init = ax.get_ylim()
x_init = ax.get_xlim()
sim_data.apply(lambda x : plot_pie(x, ax, r=7), axis=1)
# from zero to xlim/ylim with step 10
_ = ax.yaxis.set_ticks(range(0, round(y_init[1])+10, 10))
_ = ax.xaxis.set_ticks(range(0, round(x_init[1])+10, 10))
_ = ax.set_title('My')
ax.set_frame_on(True)
```

[image]