# Is there a way to plot pie chart in matplotlib heatmap?

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap, pie-chart

[image]I have a heatmap with several rows and columns.
Formerly, I was plotting a circle for each (row_index,column_index) and appending this circle to a circle_list. I was adding circle_list as a collection to the axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection


def heatmap_with_circles(data_array,row_labels,column_labels,ax=None, cmap=None, norm=None, cbar_kw={}, cbarlabel="", **kwargs):

    circles=[]
    for row_index, row in enumerate(row_labels):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(column_labels):
            circles.append(plt.Circle((row_index,column_index),radius=0.4))

    col = PatchCollection(circles, array=data_array.flatten(), cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    ax.add_collection(col)

    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[1]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[0]))

    fontsize=10
    ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, fontsize=fontsize)

    #X axis labels at top
    ax.tick_params(top=True, bottom=False,labeltop=True, labelbottom=False,pad=5)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=55, ha="left", rotation_mode="anchor")

    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[1]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data_array.shape[0]+1)-.5, minor=True)

    ax.grid(which="minor", color="black", linestyle='-', linewidth=3)
    ax.tick_params(which="minor", bottom=False, left=False)


data_array=np.random.rand(3,4)
row_labels=['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3']
column_labels=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3','Column4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1.9*len(row_labels),1.2*len(column_labels)))
ax.set_aspect(1.0)
ax.set_facecolor('white')
heatmap_with_circles(data_array,row_labels,column_labels, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However, now I need to plot a pie chart instead of a circle.
And pie chart does not have (row_index,column_index)  parameters.

Is there a way to plot pie chart in each cell of matplotlib heatmap?

Updating the for loop in **heatmap_with_circles** as follows:

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(row_labels,0):
    for column_index, column in enumerate(column_labels,0):
        wedges, _ = plt.pie([20, 10, 5])
        radius = 0.45
        [w.set_center((column_index,row_index)) for w in wedges]
        [w.set_radius(radius) for w in wedges]
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can adapt [Scatter plot with pie chart markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html)?

Comment: Also take a look at [How to plot scatter pie chart using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib)

Comment: @JohanC I need gridlines and proper row and column labels

Answer (score 3):

You can access each wedge created by `plt.pie` individually and then use `set_radius` and `set_position` to rescale the different wedges.

```
wedges, _ = plt.pie([1,2,3])
x_position, y_position = 0, 0
radius = 0.2
[w.set_center((x_position,y_position)) for w in wedges]
[w.set_radius(radius) for w in wedges]
```

Edit:
On your code, in the for loop

```
    for row_index, row in enumerate(row_labels):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(column_labels):
            wedges, _ = plt.pie([1,2,3])
            [w.set_center((row_index,column_index)) for w in wedges]
            [w.set_radius(0.4) for w in wedges]
```

Comment: Can you put that wedge to a certain row_index and column_index?

Comment: You can easily make a mapping I guess, or you can align the heatmap grid to match corresponding wedges center. Espically in you case you can use x and y ticks positions as the positions for the wedges centers

Comment: Can you give me an example for the code I have provided?

Comment: Thanks, I also updated my code in that way. You can see the new figure.

Comment: Is there a way to set label for each pie chart wedge?  [w.set_label('a') for w in wedges] does not seem to work.