# matplotlib custom path markers not displaying correctly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math

just wondering if anybody has experience with matplotlib custom markers

I want each marker in my plot to be a pie chart. To achieve this, my strategy was to create custom markers using the path class, method wedge.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html

However is not displaying correctly, in particular with wedges defined with angles in the left quadrants. However, the path defined by the wedge class method seems to be correct and wedges are displayed correctly if using PathPatch and .add_patch()

See example below

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

#Create wedges from angles
angles = np.array( [0,140,160,360] ) #Wedges angles
wedges=[]
for i in range(len(angles)-1):
    angle0= angles[i]
    angle1= angles[i+1]
    
    dangle = angle1-angle0

    wedge0=None
    if dangle>0:
        wedge0= mpath.Path.wedge(angle0, angle1)
    wedge0= mpath.Path.wedge(angle0, angle1)
    wedges.append(wedge0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax2.set_ylim(-2, 2)

tab10 = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('tab10')

for i, w0 in enumerate(wedges):
    ax1.scatter(0,0, marker=w0, c = [tab10(i)], s=20000) #Use path markers
    
    patch = patches.PathPatch(w0, color=tab10(i)) #Use patch
    ax2.add_patch(patch)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot produced]

Notice that the wedge on the left plot is sticking out, which is not supposed to.

Is this a bug in the matplotlib markers' code?

Comment: When a Path is used as a marker, it automatically gets rescaled such that its largest absolute value is 0.5. Therefore, the small wedge gets scaled differently. Maybe you can group the wedges into one collection and use the collection for scattering?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was not aware that the Paths were rescalled, which makes it more difficult to control. How to group wedges into one collection and retain the ability to draw each wedge in a different colour?

Comment: Actually, I was just wondering that maybe I should scale all wedges so that they have maximum radius of 0.5, and not 1.0....

Comment: See the **second** answer in [How to plot scatter pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib) which incorporates rescaling.  Also the [tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html) uses `s1`, `s2` and `s3` for rescaling.

Comment: thank you. I can see in the examples that the pie slices are drawn point-by-point (almost pixel-by-pixel. That's an interesting solution and it will surely work in 2D scatter plots. Unfortunately it will not work in my 3D plots.

Comment: (UPDATE) I tried to reduce of the size of wedges by half (or smaller fractions using mpath affine transform scaling. That didnt work. The edge still sticks out. As JohanC said, and remind again, all markers are all resized to an absolute size of 0.5.

Comment: It would help if you'd [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70880874/edit) your question and add reproducible code of how you applied the affine transform.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the pie charts to display correctly.

Scaling by doing affine transforms does not help because the path markaers are all resized, as in
[line 495 of markers.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/markers.py#L495) .

```
def _set_custom_marker(self, path):
    rescale = np.max(np.abs(path.vertices))  # max of x's and y's.
    self._transform = Affine2D().scale(0.5 / rescale)
    self._path = path
```

My solution is to modify the vertices in the created wedges by inserting new vertices that define a bounding box, slightly larger than the circle with radius 1.

Here is the modified code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def getBoundedWedge(angle0, angle1):
    wedge0= mpath.Path.wedge(angle0, angle1)
    #print(f"wedge0:{wedge0}")

    vertices = wedge0.vertices
    codes = wedge0.codes

    #Add ghost vertices to define bounding box
    vertices= np.insert( vertices, 0, [[1.1,1.1], [-1.1,1.1] , [-1.1,-1.1], [1.1,-1.1]] , axis=0)
    codes = np.insert( codes, 0, [1,1,1,1])

    wedgeextra = mpath.Path(vertices, codes)
    
    return wedgeextra

#Create wedges from angles
angles = np.array( [0,140,160,360] ) #Wedges angles
wedges=[]
for i in range(len(angles)-1):
    angle0= angles[i]
    angle1= angles[i+1]
    
    dangle = angle1-angle0

    wedge0=None
    if dangle>0:
        wedge0= getBoundedWedge(angle0, angle1)
    wedges.append(wedge0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax2.set_ylim(-2, 2)

tab10 = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('tab10')

for i, w0 in enumerate(wedges):
    ax1.scatter(0,0, marker=w0, c = [tab10(i)], s=20000) #Use path markers
    
    patch = patches.PathPatch(w0, color=tab10(i)) #Use patch
    ax2.add_patch(patch)

plt.show()
```

And the output is as follows

[image: output]