# Scatter Plot with Pie Chart Markers - Creating Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a scatter plot where each of the markers is a pie chart. I would like to create a legend for the pie chart. Primarily, I would like to be able to generate a legend based on the pie chart.

Another issue I have is that the pie charts that are being generated from this code are not color-coded the same way. For example, I would want all the entries from `df.A` to be red, `df.B` to be blue, etc, etc. But they are randomly assigned and not consistent between points. Ultimately, I would want the legend to be something along the lines of A = Red, B = Blue, etc as well.

This is my attempt at making the plot based on this question: [How to plot scatter pie chart using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('seaborn')
import numpy as np


def draw_pie(dist, 
             xpos, 
             ypos, 
             size, 
             ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

    # for incremental pie slices
    cumsum = np.cumsum(dist)
    cumsum = cumsum/ cumsum[-1]
    pie = [0] + cumsum.tolist()

    for r1, r2 in zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:]):
        angles = np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2)
        x = [0] + np.cos(angles).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(angles).tolist()

        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])

        ax.scatter([xpos], [ypos], marker=xy, s=size)
    return ax

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
markersize = [3,3,5,5,7]


df=pd.read_excel('subplot_data.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet4", index_col=0)
df = df.replace(0,1)
ax = plt.axes()

temp = []
for i in range(20):
    temp.append([df.A[i+1],df.B[i+1],df.C[i+1],df.D[i+1]])

for i in range(20):
    draw_pie(temp[i],x[i],y[i],markersize[i],ax=ax)
```

This gets me halfway there, but the issue of the legend and getting the color scheme between points to be consistent exists.

I have tried messing with the `plt.legend()` but I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing so I haven't made much progress.

Comment: In the question linked by you, the second answer uses colours. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Ahh yes! I was able to get that to work using the second answer, but I am still unsure of how to get a legend.