# Inaccurate pie slice sizes in a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, pie-chart

Created a scatter plot with pie charts as symbols. This works, but the size of some of the slices come out slightly different, although the sizes of all slices in a particular pie are exactly the same.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function to create the markers
def get_piechart4_markers (fraction_lst):

    cat1_lst = []
    cat2_lst = []
    cat3_lst = []
    cat4_lst = []
    
    for frc in fraction_lst:
        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, frc[0]))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, frc[0]))

        cat1_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]

        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(frc[0], frc[1]))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(frc[0], frc[1]))

        cat2_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]
    
        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(frc[1], frc[2]))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(frc[1], frc[2]))

        cat3_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]
    
        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(frc[2], 1))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(frc[2], 1))

        cat4_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]
        
    return cat1_lst, cat2_lst, cat3_lst, cat4_lst

# Convert to Arrays for plotting
x_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
pie_size_lst = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000]
pie_slice_lst = [[0.02, 0.04, 0.08],
                 [0.04, 0.08, 0.16],
                 [0.06, 0.12, 0.24],
                 [0.08, 0.16, 0.32],
                 [0.10, 0.20, 0.40]]

# Get the marker symbols
pie_cat1_lst, pie_cat2_lst, pie_cat3_lst, pie_cat4_lst = get_piechart4_markers( pie_slice_lst )

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Plot the pie slices
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat1_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='red', alpha=0.9, zorder=10, edgecolors='none')
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat2_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='green', alpha=0.9, zorder=10, edgecolors='none')
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat3_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='blue', alpha=0.9, zorder=10, edgecolors='none')
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat4_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='grey', alpha=0.9, zorder=10, edgecolors='none')

ax.set_xlim(0,6)
ax.set_ylim(0,6)

fig.tight_layout()
image_file_str = r'test_bubble.png'
fig.savefig(image_file_str, facecolor='w', dpi=1000)
```

I was expecting all the pie slices to have the same size. Initially I tried increasing to 1000dpi but it did not solve the problem.

The original code I took from this discussion [Scatter plots with pie-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib)

#### resulting plot

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: You could highly improve your question if you'd add some reproducible test data. And maybe also a link to the original code you adapted.

Comment: You are absolutely right @JohanC. I modified the question with reproducible code.

Comment: You might want to use a function for creating the x/y lists, and use kwargs for the common parameters of `ax.scatter`. There is a lot of redundant code. You can just add a second loop and zip the list of pies data `pie_cat{n}_lst` and a list of colors `colors = "red green blue grey".split()` for example.

Comment: Thanks @Guimote. WIll definitely try that later, but I am a bit of a beginner so that will take me at least a day to figure out. And I don't think that that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about it a bit more and the problem may be that the algorithm uses both the opening angle and the radius of the slice to come up with the correct 'size' (i.e. area) of the marker. Especially for smaller opening angles, when the shape becomes more linear, it chooses a different radius. The workaround is to give the slices a minimum opening angle and let them overlap. The zorder in the plotting part is now critically important of course. It is ugly and not full-proof, but it helps me for now and (as long as I don't use semi-transparant markers) nobody will know.

[resulting plot with workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgPoq.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function to create the markers
def get_piechart4_markers (fraction_lst):

    cat1_lst = []
    cat2_lst = []
    cat3_lst = []
    cat4_lst = []
    
    min_slice_val = 0.25
    
    for frc in fraction_lst:
        
        # Start value is correct, end value based uses minumum fraction cutoff
        start_val = 0
        end_val = start_val + np.maximum( min_slice_val, frc[0] - start_val)
        
        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))

        cat1_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]

        # Start value is correct, end value based uses minumum fraction cutoff
        start_val = frc[0]
        end_val = start_val + np.maximum( min_slice_val, frc[1] - start_val)

        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))

        cat2_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]
    
        # Start value is correct, end value based uses minumum fraction cutoff
        start_val = frc[1]
        end_val = start_val + np.maximum( min_slice_val, frc[2] - start_val)

        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))

        cat3_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]
    
        # Start value is correct, end value based uses minumum fraction cutoff
        start_val = frc[2]
        end_val = 1

        # first define the ratios
        x_lst = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))
        y_lst = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(start_val, end_val))

        cat4_lst += [np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x_lst, y_lst])])]
        
    return cat1_lst, cat2_lst, cat3_lst, cat4_lst

# Convert to Arrays for plotting
x_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
pie_size_lst = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000]

pie_slice_lst = [[0.02, 0.04, 0.08],
                 [0.04, 0.08, 0.16],
                 [0.06, 0.12, 0.24],
                 [0.08, 0.16, 0.32],
                 [0.10, 0.20, 0.40]]


# Get the marker symbols
pie_cat1_lst, pie_cat2_lst, pie_cat3_lst, pie_cat4_lst = get_piechart4_markers( pie_slice_lst )

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Plot the pie slices
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat1_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='red', alpha=1, zorder=21, edgecolors='none')
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat2_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='green', alpha=1, zorder=22, edgecolors='none')
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat3_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='blue', alpha=1, zorder=23, edgecolors='none')
for xp, yp, mr, sm in zip(x_arr, y_arr, pie_cat4_lst, pie_size_lst):
   ax.scatter(xp, yp, marker=mr, s=sm, color='grey', alpha=1, zorder=24, edgecolors='none')

ax.set_xlim(0,6)
ax.set_ylim(0,6)

fig.tight_layout()
image_file_str = r'test_bubble_workaround.png'
fig.savefig(image_file_str, facecolor='w', dpi=1000)
```