# Custom multi-coloured markers in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I need to plot a geographical distribution of five different instruments. Some locations can have only 1 instrument whereas other locations can have a combination of more than 1 instrument.

I want to use a marker which would indicate which combination of instruments is present at each location. My idea is to use a pentagon equally divided into 5 triangles. Each instrument will have its assigned position and colour in one of the constituting triangles. Hence, if there is only one instrument present, only one triangle would be filled and the others would be blank/transparent, whereas if all 5 instruments are present at one location, the full multi-coloured pentagon would be plotted.

After making a coloured pentagon and in draw.io and saving it as an svg, I tried using this [Tutorial (Making custom matplotlib markers)](https://petercbsmith.github.io/marker-tutorial.html) but found out that it only plots mono-coloured.

I would kindly appreciate if anybody has any advice/solutions, and I'm also open to explore other methods too to achieve this goal.

Comment: See e.g. [How to plot scatter pie chart using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib)